# Rename bulk of folder if matching content of a file

Tags: linux, bash

I have 6000 folders. Examples :

```
Niceman Production
Jingle Production
Watch Production
```

I have a file containing :

```
Title: Watch Production Code: SL-990
Title: Jingle Production Code: UOP-222
Title: Niceman Production Code: KP-290
```

What I need to do is to rename the folders above if their name matches a line from this file. The new name must be this:

```
Niceman Production KP-290
Watch Production SL-990
Jingle Production UOP-222
```

Is it possible in bash scripting to do that ?

Comment: Welcome to SO, on SO we encourage users to do add their efforts which they have put in order to solve their own problems, so please do add the same in your question and let us know then.

Comment: I have no idea what to do sir, I do have using a perl rename() but I didn't find a feature that can compare from a single file

Comment: ok, is it all folders are having `PRODUCTION` in their names like your shown samples?

Comment: Nope sir, the point is combining the string of title + code, then rename if any folder exists (with condition match folder name to title name)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my take on that.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

##: Save the contents of the file in an array name contents
mapfile -t contents < file.txt 

##: Loop through the directories
while IFS= read -r -d '' directories; do
  for i in "${contents[@]}"; do ##: Loop through the file contents
    if [[ $i = *${directories#*./}* ]]; then ##: If they both match
      echo  mv -v "$directories" "$directories ${i##* }" ##: Rename to the desired output.
    fi
  done
done < <(find . ! -name . -type d -print0)  ##: Look for directories using find.
```

- Same thing as what `@Oguz ismail` did, remove the `echo` if you think the output is correct.

---

A test run.

```
mkdir -p /tmp/testing123 && cd /tmp/testing123
```

```
mkdir -p 'Niceman Production'
mkdir -p 'Jingle Production'
mkdir -p 'Watch Production'
```

Make sure the `script` and the file is inside the same directory.

```
bash ./myscript
```

Output

```
renamed './Watch Production' -> './Watch Production SL-990'
renamed './Niceman Production' -> './Niceman Production KP-290'
renamed './Jingle Production' -> './Jingle Production UOP-222'
```

Comment: ./test.sh: line 11: syntax error near unexpected token `<'
./test.sh: line 11: `done < <(find . -type d -print0)'

it is the error sir. I really don't understand what to do next

Comment: Make sure you're using `bash` and not `sh`

Comment: The shebang should as what in the script, and Don't execute it like `sh ./myscript` you can execute it with `bash ./myscript` instead, if the script is not executable, otherwise just `./myscript`

Comment: ahhh.. done.. thank you very much sir. i really dont know difference between sh and bash, thank you once again